# python script that came with program doesn't seem to find the program module

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew

I just installed Gubbins using [their homebrew instructions](http://sanger-pathogens.github.io/gubbins/). Everything seemed to go smoothly and gubbins is now in `/usr/local/Cellar/gubbins/1.1.1/bin/gubbins`. I'm supposed to be able to use it by running their script `run_gubbins.py` and giving it an input file. But I get the following error:

```
>$ /usr/local/Cellar/gubbins/1.1.1/usr/bin/run_gubbins.py test.fasta
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/gubbins/1.1.1/usr/bin/run_gubbins.py", line 25, in <module>
    from gubbins import common
ImportError: No module named gubbins
```

Looking inside the `run_gubbins.py` script I see that the first things it does is

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
import argparse
from gubbins import common
```

So what might be happening? How come the script within a program package is not recognizing the program it came with? Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thank you so much.

```
Install homebrew from brew.sh
Open a terminal and enter these commands
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python - --user
export PATH=~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:${PATH}
easy_install pip
pip install --user dendropy
pip install --user biopython
pip install --user reportlab
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install http://sanger-pathogens.github.io/gubbins/fastml.rb
brew install http://sanger-pathogens.github.io/gubbins/gubbins.rb
```